# Building a priority list of models

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I build a Django model (or dictionary/list) to define a priority list to my CategorySources model?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', unique=True, max_length=35)
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField('Shortcut')

class Source(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', unique=True, max_length=35)
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=255)

class CategorySource(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category_source')
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, related_name='category_source')
    url = models.CharField('RSS Feed Url', max_length=2000)
```

I want to create a model or dictionary that says, for category X use first the source Y, then source Z, then source W, etc.

I thought about adding a priority number in CategorySource model but it would be hard to manage if I have a lot of categories and sources...

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "hard to manage"? Do you mean it would be troublesome to insert a Source in the middle of the priority list, as you would need to renumber the rest?

Comment: Exactly, if I set a Source priority number to an existing number I would have to shift the other sources. I thought maybe there is an easier way to accomplish this but, yes, this is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a semi-crazy proposal.

Putting a priority number in `CategorySource` is basically the only way to do it.

However, there are ways to optimize the reordering operation. This is one of them:

This idea is taken from the old BASIC programming practice, where you initially assign line numbers that are multiples of 10 or even 100 to each line, and then if you need to insert a new line in the middle, you just assign a number halfway between the two original lines.

So you assign priority numbers that are multiples of some powers of 2 - e.g. 1024:

```
Apple:      1024
Banana:     2048
Lemon:      3072
Pineapple:  4096
Grapefruit: 5120
```

And when you change the orders, e.g. move Grapefruit between Banana and Lemon, you assign a priority number in the middle, like so:

```
Apple:      1024
Banana:     2048
Grapefruit: 2560
Lemon:      3072
Pineapple:  4096
```

As you perform more re-ordering, the distance between the elements will keep shrinking until some of them are right next to each other. e.g.:

```
Banana:     2048
Pineapple:  2049
Grapefruit: 2050
Apple:      2816
Lemon:      3072
```

Let's say you now want to move Lemon between Pineapple and Grapefruit. You realise that you can't assign any integer between 2049 and 2050 - you can detect that through a `unique_together` database constraint. So you lock the relevant `Category` *and* `CategorySource` rows (using Django's `select_for_update`) and renumber all of them at once, such that they now get new priority numbers that are multiples of 1024 again.

The advantage is that you don't need to renumber many elements every time you want to change the order.